# clockwise and counter clockwise DC motar in Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

anyone knows how to build sim_model for (clockwise and counter clockwise rotation) DC motar? And I need to control the motar from workspace data.
Clearly, like this , I have <151x1 double> value from workspace.This data were to control device`s movement(displacement) from center X.I have <151x1 double> means 151 times from <1x1 double>.So in <1x1 double> state,I have 1.65800000000000 (in mm unit) .
So I need to divide 2 this value for -x and +x. And how to build sim_model for DC motar and how to connect workspace and model. Thanks for all. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common Simulink demo. Google and you will find lots of ideas, like:

http://www.library.cmu.edu/ctms/ctms/simulink/examples/motor/motorsim.htm

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11587-dc-motor-model-simulink

Comment: Thanks for advice.But these link I already saw it and downloaded.Any others? for clockwise and counter clockwise rotation.